# Could ultrasound pings and triangulation really help de-scatter diffuse red light for imaging?

Tags: visible-light, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, scattering, doppler-effect

Does the science explanation in the latest OpenWater TED talk make sense in principle? The claim involves taking advantage of the doppler effect. Could someone give a more detailed explanation as to why it could work?

https://youtu.be/FMiOIqysm_k?t=332

Comment: Questions on Stack Exchange sites need to be self-contained. You may use links to enhance them, but the question must make sense without readers referring to the links.

Comment: okay I reworded it